# jQuery conditional: if div has a particular ID, add class to another div

Tags: jquery, css, conditional-statements

I am trying to get a jQuery conditional to apply a class to this particular element –  – when another element contains a particular ID. Here's what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if( $('.container-fluid').hasId('europe') === true ) 
{
 $('controlBar_playerVideo1').addClass('darkcontrols');
}
});
</script>
```

Here's the live site: http://fsa.space/

When I add the script above to the footer I get an "undefined is not a function" error in the console. I should mention I am a total jQuery novice (which should be abundantly apparent).

I would be grateful if someone could provide pointers to achieve this.

Comment: does the `.container-fluid` exist more than once inside your dom?

Comment: I don't see any class "container-fluid", check it again. And one more, do you add the Jquery Library to your html?

Comment: Daivd: Yep it's in line 218: <div class="container-fluid hidden-phone hidden-tablet" id="europe">

jQuery 1.11.2 is loaded automatically in this WP version

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
if ($('.container-fluid').attr("id") == "europe") {
         $('controlBar_playerVideo1').addClass('darkcontrols');
  }
 });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. I tried your code and got this error in the console: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Comment: i'm sorry just correct ($'.container-fluid') this to ($('.container-fluid')

Comment: i missed ( i'm so sorry

Comment: I made this change and I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in this console. See live: http://fsa.space

Comment: i already check it live i saw this error "TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: I tried that and the "$ is not a function" error is gone, but the class is not added to the <span id="controlBar_playerVideo1"> element as desired. Here's what I currently have:

`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
if (jQuery('.container-fluid').attr("id") == "europe") {
         jQuery('controlBar_playerVideo1').addClass('darkcontrols');
  }
 });
    </script>`

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated because hasId() is not jquery function. To get the id of the element you could you use [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/) or [attr('id')](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

```
if($('.container-fluid').is('#europe')) 
{
    $('controlBar_playerVideo1').addClass('darkcontrols');
}
```

**OR**

```
if($('.container-fluid').attr('id') == 'europe') 
{
    $('controlBar_playerVideo1').addClass('darkcontrols');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `$('#europe.container-fluid').size() > 0` which means "are there elements with id `europe` and CSS class `container-fluid`?".

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `toggleClass()` with a boolean switch (if it evaluates to true, the supplied class-name is added, otherwise it's removed, or simply not added):

```
$('controlBar_playerVideo1'). toggleClass('darkcontrols',  $('#europe.container-fluid').length);
```

References:

- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jQuery.com/toggleClass);

Comment: Thanks David. You'll have to excuse my complete jQuery ignorance, would this be the correct syntax for this function?

`<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('controlBar_playerVideo1'). toggleClass('darkcontrols',  jQuery('#europe.container-fluid').length);
 });
</script>`

(I tried this code above and the class was not added to my <span id="controlBar_playerVideo1"> element)

Answer (score 0):

Thought I would share how I got this to work. I used Ali's solution but for some reason the script wouldn't apply a class to my element  (perhaps because it already had a class?). As soon as I switched the target element from #controlBar_playerVideo1 to html, the class 'darkcontrols' was applied to

So here was the final script that worked for me:

`<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        if (jQuery('.container-fluid').attr("id") == "europe") {
        jQuery('html').addClass('darkcontrols');
    }
    });
</script>`

Thanks Ali & co for contributing!